# Can I use jQuery OpenID Plugin with LightopenID?

Tags: openid, selector, lightopenid

I'm using [LightopenID](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/) and all works fine. But I want a pretty openID selector, and I was trying [jQuery OpenID](http://jvance.com/pages/jQueryOpenIdPlugin.xhtml)
It's working, but I'm lost when it must call to LightopenID. I think is this line:

```
<form class="openid" method="post" action="/Login.xhtml?ReturnUrl=">
```

isn't it? Any idea, please?

Can I use another selector? Any code example, please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the line you've mentioned. You have to set the form's action so that it points to a file that will handle your authentication. One such file is the example.php bundled with LightOpenID.

I took the following steps to test it:

1. Downloaded and extracted LightOpenID to `/openid` ( so that http://localhost/openid/example.php would point at the example)
2. Downloaded and extracted jQuery OpenID plugin, so it's in `/openid/jQueryOpenIdPlugin`
3. Changed the action to `'../example.php'` in '/openid/jQueryOpenIdPlugin/Login.xhtml'
4. Opened http://localhost/openid/jQueryOpenIdPlugin/Login.xhtml
5. Entered an openid, then clicked submit.
6. Been redirected to the authentication page -- now I'm sure it works.